# Can't get maximum id with of table with CDbCriteria

Tags: yii

Hi I'm trying to **get the maximum id of a table with 'CDbCriteria' in yii**

This is my code,

```
$model = new PackageImages;
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='max(package_image_id) AS maxColumn';
$row = $model->model()->find($criteria);
echo $row['maxColumn'];
```

But when I instead get maximum 'package_image_id' I get this issue,

```
Property "PackageImages.maxColumn" is not defined.
```

Comment: check data using `print_r($row);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this Line according to it](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/6730-how-can-i-use-max-in-find-method/page__p__80659#entry80659):->

In **order for**

> $row['maxColumn']

**to be a valid command** (and not throw an error) you **should define inside your** class a variable as

> public $maxColumn;